# TCP Connection Failure issues in latest bunny version (2.0.0)

Tags: ruby, bunny

I'm trying out the Bunny amqp client gem version 2.0.0. And while I was trying I found the following error :

W, [2015-08-03T07:36:21.913706 #9100]  WARN -- #: Could not establish TCP connection to 10.223.19.94:5672: 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bunny-2.0.0/lib/bunny/session.rb:298:in `rescue in start': Could not establish TCP connection to any of the configured hosts (Bunny::TCPConnectionFailedForAllHosts)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bunny-2.0.0/lib/bunny/session.rb:264:in`start'
    from rabbit-client-test.rb:12:in `<main>`

Also, I noticed that the same error does not occur in the previous version of bunny 1.7.0. Is it something related to gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Bunny latest gem works only with Ruby 2.0+. I guess the latest version of gem should not get installed if we have older versions.